# Как получить Высоту\Ширину imageVIew из Android.Support.V4.Fragment(всегда возвращает 0)

Tags: android, android-fragment, xamarin, treeview

Я использую V4.**Fragments**.
Соответственно из активити, создаю новый экземпляр моего фрагмента и затем начинаю транзанкцию.
Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо знать, какая ширина\высота засетилась в контрол ImageView. В самом layout,имеем следующее :

```
<ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/imgView" />
```

На текущий момент,пробовал реализацию интерфейса **IOnGlobalLayoutListener**(создал отдельный класс)

```
     class GlobalLayoutListener : Java.Lang.Object, ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener
        {
            System.Action _OnGlobalLayout;

            public GlobalLayoutListener (System.Action onGlobalLayout)
            {
                this._OnGlobalLayout = onGlobalLayout;
            }

            public void OnGlobalLayout ()
            {
                _OnGlobalLayout ();
            }
        }
```

После чего, в классе моего фрагмента, делаю вот это :

```
           public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    Arguments = new Bundle();
                    View _View = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragmentLayout, container, false);
                    imgView = _View.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgView);

                Action CallBack = () =>
                {
                    ImgHeight = imgView.Height;
                    ImgWidth = imgView.Width;
                };
           //new instance of class,that implements IOnGlobalLayoutListener
            GlobalLayoutListener Global = new GlobalLayoutListener(CallBack);
            imgView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(Global);  
retun _View;
}
```

К сожалению не сработало(все получаю 0 как результат).
Вторым вариантом я реализовал интерфейс прямиком в самом фрагменте:

```
 public class MyCustomFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment,View.IOnTouchListener,ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener 
    {
        int ImgHeight;
        int ImgWidth;
        ImageView imgView;
        Bundle Arguments;

  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                Arguments = new Bundle();
                View _View = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragmentLayout, container, false);
                imgView = _View.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgView);

        ViewTreeObserver Vto = imgView.ViewTreeObserver; //also tried with _View.ViewTreeObserver; result same
        Vto.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    retun _View;
}
```

Аналогично,результат 0.
И что еще в голову пришло:

```
        public class MyCustomFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
            {
                int ImgHeight;
                int ImgWidth;
                ImageView imgView;
                Bundle Arguments;



  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                Arguments = new Bundle();
                View _View = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragmentLayout, container, false);
                imgView = _View.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgView);

        imgView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += (sender, e) =>  //also tried with _View
                {
                    ImgHeight = imgView.Height;
                    ImgWidth = imgView.Width;
                };

    retun _View;
}
```

Но не сработало. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается,все работает корректно.Ивент выстреливает,соответственно получаю нужные мне значения:

```
   imgView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += (sender, e) =>  //also tried with _View
                    {
                        ImgHeight = imgView.Height;
                        ImgWidth = imgView.Width;
                    };
```

Код полностью рабочий!

Answer (score 2):

Размеры виджетов не известны до вызова метода `onResume`. Следовательно вам надо получать их размеры именно в методе `onResume`. На яве можно и до `onResume`, но это зачастую нетривиальная задача.

Comment: Да,на Xamarin'e тоже можно. Посредстом TreeViewObserver'a. Вот только не совсем понимаю где моя ошибка

Comment: Может, проблема в том, что вы (первый ваш вариант) сначчала запрашиваете измерения, и только потом вешаете слушатель?

Comment: в каком именно случае?(там 3 варианта)

Comment: 3-ий снизу...Но это лишь догадка - я в этом-вашем-xamarin-е не разбираюсь)

Comment: нее,не то. Предложи вариант на jave,а я переделаю под себя.